# How to add numbers without +

Tags: java, integer-arithmetic

I was asked this question on the interview. I didn't answer and actually I don't understand how it works.

```
int add(int x, int y)
{
    while (y != 0)
    {
        int carry = x & y;  
        x = x ^ y; 
        y = carry << 1;
    }
    return x;
}
```

I'm not asking why does it produce a correct answer... First of all, why does the algorithm eventually stop? To me it's not that obvious.

In order for it to stop, `carry` has to become `0`. Can't someone explain it in a nutshell?

Comment: It's a [full adder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_%28electronics%29#Full_adder). After you shift left 32 times, there will be 32 zero bits (which is `0`).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Well... yes)). But  it's not explained why it works.

Comment: @Alupkers You asked why algorithm stops? Exactly as @ElliottFrisch said: `curry << 1` sets the right-most bit to 0. In at most 32 steps (integers are 32 bit wide in Java) all bits are 0 so `y==0` and the loop ends.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
line 1 : int carry = x & y;

line 2 : x = x ^ y;

line 3 : y = carry << 1;
```

if x = 1; y = 2;

Binary for each number:

0 = 00

1 = 01

2 = 10

3 = 11

for line 1 code,

& (bitwise AND)
Binary AND Operator copies a bit to the result if it exists in both operands

x is 1    => 01

y is 2    => 10

result carry is => 00 (0)

for line 2 code,

^ (bitwise XOR)
Binary XOR Operator copies the bit if it is set in one operand but not both.

x is 1    => 01

y is 2    => 10

result x is => 11 (3)

for line 3 code,
variable carry needs to shift left for 1 bit,
so now carry is 0 => 00 and shift 1 bit left means carry is now 0. The result y is (0). And while loop stop because y is 0 now.

The final result for x is 3.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: `x & y` is bitwise and, not logical and. carry will still be 0 here, but for entirely different reasons than you stated.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take an example:

```
x=13(1101)
y=9(1001)

Loop 1:
-----------------
y!=0 -> carry=(1101)&(1001)=1001(9)  [AND Op]
x=(1101)^(1001)=0100(4)   [XOR Op]
y=carry<<1 -> y=(carry)x2=10010(18)

Loop 2:
-----------------
y!=0 -> carry=(0100)&(10010)=00000(0)
x=(0100)^(10010)=10110(22)
y=carry<<1 -> y=0

loop terminated.
```

therefore,x is 22.So,x^y store the sum part and x&y store the carry part,and then carry(x&y) is shifted to match the digit with x^y,and finnally XOR them and store into x.
x is the resultant.

Comment: If you design a full adder with boolean logic you will get the answer clear

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell its about using y (and the "carries/x&y" it becomes) to modify x until it becomes the sum of both ints. For example,

```
y=1 (....0001), x=anything (either .....0 or .....1)
if x ends with 0, x&y=0
    //x^y = x becomes ....001 (thereby adding 1)
    //since x&y=0 the loop stops
if x ends with 1, x&y=1
    //x^y = x
    //since y= x&y<<1, new y=(.....000010)
    if x ends with 01, x&y=0
        //x^y = x becomes ....010 (thereby adding 1)
        //since x&y=0 the loop stops
    if x ends with 11, x&y=1
        //x^y = .....01
        //since y= x&y<<1, new y=(......000100)
        if x ends with 011
            //stuff happens and x becomes ....100 (thereby adding 1)
            //loop stops
        if x ends with 111
            //...
            //if x ends with 111111, x becomes ....1000000 (thereby adding 1)
            //if x ends with 1111111, x becomes ....10000000 (thereby adding 1)
            //if x ends with 11111111, x becomes ....100000000 (thereby adding 1)
            //well you get the idea
```

The same logic is applicable to all values of y, and is not that much different from normal addition only that there are now 2 possible digits (0 and 1) instead of the usual 10 (0 to 9).